# error_log PHP error log found. This file must not be in the production version of the theme. (wordpress theme check plugin)

Tags: php, themes

This appears when I [check my theme](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/theme-check/) but I can't see the error.log file. This is my wp-config configuration:

```
// Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

// Disable display of errors and warnings
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );

// Use dev versions of core JS and CSS files (only needed if you are modifying these core files)
define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );
```

Comment: Does the log file exist? You may have to manually create it before WordPress can write to it.

Comment: It looks like it'll warn for any file with "error_log" anywhere in its name. If that doesn't help, I'd modify the check in `theme-check/checks/class-file-check.php` to return the complete filename matched so you can see what it's warning about.

Comment: thanks, but now it is no longer just for a curiosity how would you rewrite the file?